# VPN connection and internet access, but "No internet, secured" --> So I can't turn Mobile Hotspot on

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, vpn, hotspot, connection-sharing

When I am connected through my VPN, Windows 10 reports "no internet, secured" even though the internet works perfectly fine through the VPN. (NordVPN killswitch is on.)

The problem is that Mobile hotspot (Windows settings) is reporting I don't have an internet connection. I want to share the VPN adapter connection (I know how to do that).

> "We can't set up mobile hotspot because your PC doesn't have an
> Ethernet, Wi-Fi, or cellular data connection."

The USB adapter I'm using works to create a hotspot with Windows' "Mobile hotpot," but I can't do it from the command line (that I know of) because it doesn't support hosted networks (from "netsh wlan show drivers").

I need to get Windows to recognize there's really an internet connection, while keeping the VPN firewall restricted as it is (or only allow what's necessary, without allowing any non-VPN traffic to leave the PC, including DNS searches outside of the VPN tunnel).

Comment: It appears your VPN connection is not permitting split tunnel.  Can you enable split tunnel?

Comment: That's the point. VPN only.